# Simulate experiment with R Programming

Tags: r, probability, rundeck

I am new in R programming. I need to solve 1 problem in R. I need to simulate the following experiment in R. 
A poker hand consists of 5 cards dealt from a conventional pack of 52 cards, the order of the cards not being important. Find the probability that a given hand has at least one king and at least one queen.

I know how to find for atleast 1 king but not for  at least one king and at least one queen. for atleast 1 king code is :

```
deck<- rep(1:13 , each=4)
#here J=11 , Q=12, K=13
nhands <- 1000
Xk<- c(rep(-1, nhands))
for( i in 1:nhands){
hand <- sample( deck , 5 , replace= FALSE)
numberofK<-0
for( j in 1:5){ # count Kings
if( hand[j] == 13){
numberofK <- numberofK +1
}
}
#print(numberofK)
Xk[i] <-numberofK
#print(hand)
}
table(Xk) /nhands
```

Can anyone please help me in coding the required 1.. Thanks

Comment: Already answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541220/what-is-the-probability-of-of-drawing-at-least-one-king-and-one-ace-in-a-five-ca

Comment: If it is about at least one king, why do you need to keep track of the number of kings?

Comment: Thanks duffymo . I know theortically but I need to code it in R and I am new to R.

Comment: Yes, You are right Psidom. I just created this code because it will help me even keeping the track of 0 , 1 , 2 , 3. Can you please help me in coding the required/

Comment: So you do need to know how many kings and queens you have within each hand?

Answer (score 2):

The probability of a hand of `5` cards that contain at least one king or one queen can be simply written as following, where `sample(deck, 5)` gives a hand of `5` cards while `any(c(12, 13) ...)` checks whether `King` or `Queen` is within the hand and `sum` counts how many times such case happens within the 1000 simulation:

```
set.seed(10)
sum(sapply(1:100000, function(i) { any(c(12, 13) %in% sample(deck, 5))}))/100000
# [1] 0.58365
```

Theoretically, the probability of such case would be:

```
(choose(52, 5) - choose(44, 5))/choose(52, 5)
# [1] 0.5821375
```

Which are pretty close.

And on the other hand, if it is indeed **And** which means at least a king and a queen, simulation gives:

```
set.seed(10)
sum(sapply(1:100000, function(i) { all(c(12, 13) %in% sample(deck, 5))}))/100000
# [1] 0.09932
```

And theoretically:

```
(choose(52, 5) - choose(44, 5) - (2*(choose(48, 5) - choose(44, 5))))/choose(52, 5)
# [1] 0.1001785
```

And the number matches closely.

Comment: Thanks Psidom. But theortically when I solve this question, it gives 0.58 .

Comment: I want to find the probability that a given hand has at least one king and at least one queen.

Comment: so `all` means both `12` and `13` should be within the hand and returns true if it is the case, I don't see particular problem about this but I'll see how the theory goes, update later.

Comment: I think you are looking for at least one King **or** one Queen instead of **and**.

Comment: No, I am looking for atleast 1 king and 1 queen

Comment: But the probability you are giving is more close to **OR**. see the update, the probability of **OR** is 0.58214.

Comment: What do you think for and , any should be replacerd by what? Actually I need and want to find p(“at least one K and one Q”)=27017/46410≈0.58214

Comment: sum(sapply(1:10000, function(i) {(c(12, 13) %in% sample(deck, 5))}))/10000

Comment: See the update, for **and** `any` should be replaced by `all` which means both `12` and `13` should be within the hand.

Comment: Let me check. please

Comment: You are welcome to accept the answer if it helps. :)-

Comment: I am getting 0.1042 with your answer for and.

Comment: The number varies from experiment to experiment because of the sample function, if you want a consistent number use `set.seed()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You really helped me in a problem where I was struck off for too long time

Comment: Can you alos give me some idea about biased coin tossing. Actually I did google but got nothing. If you have time and don't worry , can you please?

Comment: You can ask another question on stack overflow or stack exchange and explicitly explain the problem. I believe there will be people including me helping you out.

Comment: Okay . But Now I will be able to ask tomorrow only not today